How can I prove inequality?
I have an inequality to prove,
$$\left| {M + 2\sum\limits_{m = 1}^M {{{\bar \alpha }_m}} } \right| \le \left| {2M + \sum\limits_{m = 1}^M {{\alpha _m}} } \right|$$
where,
$${\alpha _m} = {e^{ - im}}$$
M is natural number, and the upperbar denotes the complex conjugation.
Can someone let me know how to prove this inequality?
Thanks in advance.
======================================
Solved!


Show some effort. What have you tried?

With successive use of triangle inequality $$\left| {a + b} \right| \le \left| a \right| + \left| b \right|$$ and  $${\alpha _m}|,|{{\bar \alpha }_m}| = 1$$, I could derive that both LHS and RHS are less than 3M. But, I could not go forward anymore.

how about evaluating the geometric progressions and then comparing the absolute values?

For the difficulty of this problem, if that's all you have tried, then you need to try harder. And you need to put your attempts in the body of your question please.

Thanks. I will.

To be fair, it's not an easy question  and I haven't solved it yet. But you still have to show that you have tried several avenues.

@JayLee You may show your attempt for reopening this question.

The problem is now solved (please see the  attached photo). Thanks for your concern.

@JayLee Congratulations!
